# Best practice on deleting/zeroing out a security sensitive image?

Tags: java, android, security, bitmap

Can anybody point me at resources with best practice on clearing sensitive runtime images?

Consider a scenario where a sensitive image is downloaded from a server at runtime, loaded into a Bitmap object, and is then displayed in an ImageView in a Fragment.

When the user leaves that screen, or the app is exited/put in the background for a long time, then I want to clear that image data so that it isn't easy to recover.

I was wondering if there is a reliable way to zero out the bitmap data as soon as the Fragment containing the image is destroyed?

This feel tricky to me, as Bitmaps are usually returned as immutable objects, e.g. [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int)) says:

> Decode an immutable bitmap from the specified byte array.

Presumably I would have to create a mutable [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) and then copy over its data?

It looks like [recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()) won't help me, as that will just mark the data as available for garbage collection, it won't wipe it.

Comment: please add the code you're using to download this image

Comment: Have you tried: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsFromBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)

Comment: I am not using an image library, and I've ensured that I am not accidentally caching the image anywhere outside the Fragment, e.g. on disk or in memory (image libraries typically have a two level LRU cache).  The image data is encrypted during download, so HTTP caching should also not be a concern.

Comment: @Morrison, yes, I have seen the Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer method, but I haven't tried it yet - I'm asking for advice on best practice before I do detailed testing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply clear the `Bitmap` using

```
someBitmap.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

It will fill the bitmap with `TRANSPARENT` color and erase everything on it.
However, if you have no any references to your bitmap (e.g. you've set `null` to `ImageView` that was containing your `Bitmap` like this

```
someImageView.setDrawable(null)
```

the garbage collector should collect it shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @IlyaGulya for the `eraseColor` suggestion.  Below is the code I've written so far.

Creating the mutable Bitmap:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmapOptions.inMutable = true;
return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, bitmapOptions);
```

The code to clear the image data in my Fragment (I save the BitmapDrawable into a `myBitmapDrawable` field when the Fragment receives it):

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(null);

    try {
        MyUtils.zeroOutBitmapData(myBitmapDrawable.getBitmap());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        loggingUtil.logHandledException(e);
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

My utility for zeroing out a Bitmap:

```
public static void zeroOutBitmapData(Bitmap mutableBitmap) {
    if (mutableBitmap.isMutable()) {
        mutableBitmap.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
    } else {
        logger.error("Expected bitmap to be mutable");
    }
}
```

...and here is a unit test (well, an `ApplicationTestCase` since I want to test with a real Bitmap):

```
public void testZeroOutBitmap() throws Exception {
    Resources resources = getContext().getResources();

    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inMutable = true;

    Bitmap mutableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.an_example_image);

    // Assert that some pixels start out with non zero colors
    assertEquals(-789517, mutableBitmap.getPixel(0, 0));
    assertEquals(-723724, mutableBitmap.getPixel(10, 10));

    MyUtils.zeroOutBitmapData(mutableBitmap);

    // Check that pixel data has now been cleared out
    assertEquals(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT, mutableBitmap.getPixel(0, 0));
    assertEquals(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT, mutableBitmap.getPixel(10, 10));
}
```